# The variety $X=V(x^2+y^2-1) \subseteq k^2$ is isomorphic to k if and only if $k$ has characteristic 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-curves

**Question:** The variety $X=V(x^2+y^2-1) \subseteq k^2$ is isomorphic to k if and only if $k$ has characteristic 2.

I don't even know where to start....Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic $2$, what is $x^2$?

Comment: @Randall  all I know is $2x=0$ for all $x \in k$. Do you mean $x^2$ is also zero?

Comment: I think what Randall might have meant to say is that you should consider what $(x+y)^2$ is over a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, Oh I got it. Thank you for your hint !

Comment: But what about the converse? What if char $(k) \neq 2$?

Comment: @TabesBridges correctly interpreted what I was attempting to say.

Comment: @Randall, Thank you for your and Tabesbridges hint. I have got the char $(k)=2$ case. Can you give me a hint on the char $(k) \neq 2$ case?

Comment: So the key computation here, which you seem to have figured out, is that in characteristic 2, as a variety we have $V(x^2 + y^2 - 1) = V((x+y)^2 - 1) = V((x+y-1)^2) = V(x+y-1)$, which is a line hence isomorphic to $k$. In all other characteristics, the first two equalities do not hold and the polynomial is irreducible. Do you know any invariants of abstract varieties? A first approach might be trying to distinguish $k[x]$, the ring of regular functions on $k$, from $k[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$, the ring of regular functions on your conic. If you can do this you win.